# Tkinter can't lift item within canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-canvas

I have 4 items in my canvas (canvas12). I'm trying to place the 2 drag buttons (frame1_drag/frame2_drag) in front of the windows (frame2can/frame1can). But I can't get tag_raise() or lift() to do anything. Right now the drag buttons are stuck behind the windows. And yes, it has to be this way because the drag buttons animate their respective framexcan window within canvas12.

```
frame2can = canvas12.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', width=sf(768), height=sf(fr1h),window=frame2)
frame1can = canvas12.create_window(0, sf(fr1h), anchor='nw', width=sf(768), height=sf(fr1h),window=frame1)

# Drag Buttons
frame1_drag = canvas12.create_rectangle(0, 0, sf(fr0h), sf(fr0h), outline="blue", fill="green", tags="token")
frame2_drag = canvas12.create_rectangle(0, sf(fr1h), sf(fr0h), sf(fr0h+fr1h), outline="blue", fill="green", tags="token")

canvas12.tag_raise(frame1_drag)
canvas12.tag_raise(frame2_drag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place drawn items on top of window objects.

From the official tk documentation:

> The items in a canvas are ordered for purposes of display, with the first item in the display list being displayed first, followed by the next item in the list, and so on. Items later in the display list obscure those that are earlier in the display list and are sometimes referred to as being “on top” of earlier items. When a new item is created it is placed at the end of the display list, on top of everything else. Widget commands may be used to re-arrange the order of the display list.
>
> Window items are an exception to the above rules. The underlying window systems require them always to be drawn on top of other items. In addition, the stacking order of window items is not affected by any of the canvas widget commands; you must use the raise and lower Tk commands instead.